# Backbone model save triggers error callback on Chrome/FF

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, backbone.js

Noob question here:

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 and I'm trying to save an entity through Backbone. Here's what I have:

I defined my Backbone model (Program) as such:

```
var Program = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: function () {
        return { name: "" };
    },

    initialize: function (attrs) {
        this.set('name', attrs.name);
    },

    urlRoot: '/program/add'

});
```

Then I hook up the model save on the click event of a button:

```
$('.add-program').click(function () {
    var programName = $('.program-name').val();
    var program = new Program({ name: programName });
    program.save(null, {
        success: function (model, response) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (model, response) {
            alert('error');
        } 
    });
});
```

It works on IE (surprisingly!) - ProgramController.Add(string name) gets called fine and I get a success response. But **I'm having issues on Chrome and FF - They both trigger the error callback** with the slight difference that on Chrome my Controller Action doesn't even get hit at all (it does on FF though). The funny thing is that my action breakpoint does get hit on FF, with the appropriate param value, but still get the error callback.

I'm not sure what's going on here. I tried debugging through Firebug/Chromebug and don't see much on the error callback params (the errorStatus is just ... well... "error"!). I also tried looking at the Network tab and Fiddler and I don't see anything that rings a bell (maybe I'm not looking at the right place). I also tried doing a straight jquery ajax call to the controller and still get the same weird behavior.

Just in case, here's the MVC action (although I don't think the issue is here):

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Add(string name)
{
    var stubbedResponse = new {id = Guid.NewGuid()};
    return Json(stubbedResponse);
}
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Instead of alert('error') try doing a console.log(response) and see what MVC is sending back. Not sure why IE would handle it differently, but worth a shot.

Comment: no luck. The response object has a responseText: "" and statusText: "error". Not sure if any of its other properties can provide me with better feedback.

Comment: A Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Uj5Ae/2/ with your client code seems to be OK. Something with your server response? Or Backbone and Underscore versions not matching?

Comment: Or maybe the return false at the end of the click handler, if the event propagation is not handled elsewhere.

Comment: @nikoshr Good call on jsfiddle (I had forgot about it) and stopping the event propagation - that solved my problem! Noob mistake :( ... btw, please provide your answer if you want the points :)

Comment: Added an answer. Glad that solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Uj5Ae/2 with your client code seems to be OK. Something with your server response? Or Backbone and Underscore versions not matching?
Or maybe the return false at the end of the click handler, if the event propagation is not handled elsewhere.

Spoiler : that was the event propagation :)